# Word document. Замена меток

Tags: c#, парсер, doc, docx

Есть файл формата .doc/.docx. В этом файле есть метки, например:

```
...

[FirstName][MiddleName][LastName]

...

[Date]
```

Нужно заменить метки, значениями. Значения приходят в функцию со стороны js.

Использую c#.

Любые предложения.

Comment: Ищите библиотеку для работы с doc-файлами. Честно говоря. выбор невелик (в [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=doc) по сути всего одна). Уточните, речь именно о `doc`, не о `docx`?

Comment: Может быть любой. Тот, с которым проще будет решить эту задачу.

Comment: Что значит любой? txt тоже может быть?

Comment: нет .doc, либо .docx

Comment: С библиотеками для docx дело обстоит намного лучше. Ищите по ключевым словам `OpenXml`, `ClosedXml`. Или [вот](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-parse-DOCX-document-b48e4d94), например.

Comment: А метки уникальны? (их наименования)

Comment: Да, все уникальны.

Comment: Файл doc строится из страниц по 512 байт. Первая страница как правило (если в microsoft office создан файл)  находится по адресу 0x600, текст хранится в юникоде.  Если заменять "без сдвига" то получится. А если со сдвигом - боюсь прийдётся мудрить большую библиотеку. Страницы обвёрнуты в biff-8 обвёртку. Документацию где-то видел. На обвёртку проблем нету, на тело документация хуже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант через Open XML SDK 2.5 для **.docx**. Требуется ссылка на сборку WindowsBase и сам  [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Microsoft Office не требуется для работы. Проблема только в одном - InnerText элемента [Paragraph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph(v=office.14).aspx) менять напрямую нельзя, только через элементы Run, в которых и хранится сам текст, то есть при замене в данном случае теряется форматирование текста, которое хранится в [RunProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.runproperties(v=office.14).aspx). Разбираться в коде и классах SDK проще всего через рефлектор файлов в код [ссылка](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

Желтым метки выделил для демонстрации, для работы это не необходимо.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Paragraph = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph;
using Run = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run;
using Text = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text;

namespace TestC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string initialPath = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\TestDocument.docx";
            string resultPath = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\TestDocument_result.docx";
            File.Copy(initialPath, resultPath, overwrite: true);

            Dictionary<string, string> marks = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "FirstName","Иван"},
                { "LastName","Иванов"},
                { "Date",DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()},
                { "Initials","Иван И. И."},
                { "DateIssued",DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToLongDateString()}
            };

            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(resultPath, true)) {
                Body documentBody = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                List<Paragraph> paragraphsWithMarks = documentBody.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.InnerText, @".*\[\w+\].*")).ToList();
                foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphsWithMarks) {
                    foreach (Match markMatch in Regex.Matches(paragraph.InnerText, @"\[\w+\]", RegexOptions.Compiled)) {

                        string paragraphMarkValue = markMatch.Value.Trim(new[] { '[', ']' });
                        string markValueFromCollection;
                        if (marks.TryGetValue(paragraphMarkValue, out markValueFromCollection)) {
                            string editedParagraphText = paragraph.InnerText.Replace(markMatch.Value, markValueFromCollection);
                            paragraph.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
                            paragraph.AppendChild<Run>(new Run(new Text(editedParagraphText)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

До:

[image: Документ до]

После:

[image: Документ после]

Comment: При замене теряется форматирование только замененного текста?

Comment: @endovitskiiy Всего параграфа, где он содержится. Но там часть стилей идут на весь параграф (стиль Заголовок 1), к примеру, и указываются в ParagraphProperties у Paragraph. Они не теряются. Потеряются такие вещи как наклон, курсив, которые могут указываться в RunProperties на область текста (Run) внутри Paragraph. Там с этим не все так просто, конечно...

Comment: У меня в документе нет наклонов/курсивов - никакого форматирования. Только текст и таблицы и отступы. Отступы потеряются (у параграфа)?

Comment: @endovitsky, сейчас попробовал - не потерялись. Отступы и интервал

Comment: Тут два правильных ответа, не знаю какой лучше.

Comment: Ну...OpenXML я бы назвал, наверно, более правильным подходом чем  работа с процессом Microsoft Word через COM Interop.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо меток лучше использовать DocVariable [image: Добавление переменной]

тогда используя Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word можно написать примерно следующее:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

//

```
Word._Application application;     
Word._Document sdoc = null;

Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Object trueObj = true;
Object falseObj = false;

application = new Word.Application();

Object templatePathObj = @"e:\temp\template.docx";

try
{
    sdoc = application.Documents.Add(ref  templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
}
catch (Exception error)
{               
    application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
    application = null;
    throw error;
}

object variable2 = "Здесь будет значение для переменной";

if (sdoc.Variables.Count == 0)
{                   
    Word.Variable var2 = sdoc.Variables.Add("SomeField", ref variable2);
}
else
{ 
    sdoc.Variables["SomeField"].Value = variable2.ToString;
}

sdoc.Fields.Update();
application.Visible = true;
```

Comment: А можно ссылку на статью где бы подробно описывалось как задавать DocVariable в Wordе. Я никогда не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: А рисунок из Microsoft Word?

Comment: да, скриншот из Word 2013

Comment: http://101teist.blogspot.com/2011/09/c-word.html как вариант

Comment: или вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647024/filling-in-a-docvariable-in-word-docx-using-c-sharp#3647024

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения. Получилось два правильных ответа.

Comment: Странно. Я добавил несколько DocVariables в docx документ, но `sdoc.Variables.Count` у меня равен 0

Answer (score 0):

Если Microsoft Office и сборки Word Interop есть на компьютере, то можно  применить функцию Interop. Этот метод будет работать только если длина строки значения замены < 256 символов и строка замены не содержит перевод строки. Если строки замены длинные или есть переводы строк, надо искать/заменять по каждому появлению метки. Стиль метки будет применен к строке замены.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
word.Visible = true;
Word.Document wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(имяВходногоФайлаСМетками);
...
var find = word.Selection.Find;
find.Text = строкаМетки;
find.Replacement.Text = значениеДляЗамены;
find.Execute(FindText: Type.Missing, 
             MatchCase: true, 
             MatchWholeWord: true, 
             MatchWildcards: false,
             MatchSoundsLike: Type.Missing, 
             MatchAllWordForms: false, 
             Forward: true, 
             Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue,
             Format: false, 
             ReplaceWith: Type.Missing, 
             Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
wordDocument.Save()
```