# Вставить разметку html с содержимым в документ docx

Tags: c#, html, docx, openxml

У меня есть текстовый редактор (**tinymce**), где пользователь редактирует записи.
В итоге получается html код. Например такой:

```
<table><tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr></table><p>Some text</p>
```

Пользователь нажимает на кнопку - "Сформировать документ".

Данный шаблон должен подставляться в docx файл.

Для этого есть placeholder в документе - **[template]**.

Подробнее об этом здесь: [Word document. Замена меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593873/word-document-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Вопрос: как вместо html кода вставить в **docx** таблицу и параграф?

Есть такой код:

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml;
...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 const string filename = "test.docx";
 string html = Properties.Resources.DemoHtml;

 if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);

 using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
 {
      using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
      {
           MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
           if (mainPart == null)
           {
                mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
           }

           HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
           converter.ParseHtml(html);

           mainPart.Document.Save();
      }

      File.WriteAllBytes(filename, generatedDocument.ToArray());
 }

 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
}
```

Он из ресурса формирует docx файл, мне нужно вставить html в существующий файл.

Comment: Вам надо вставить разметку html с содержимым в документ docx, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, все правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью AltChunk и AlternativeFormatImportPart. Более-менее это на статье с [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/10/26/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly/) описано.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace TestC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\sample.docx", isEditable: true))
            //я вынес файл html как ресурс сборки отдельно, это не принципиально
            using (var htmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TestC.Sample.html"))
            {
                var mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var html = new StreamReader(htmlStream).ReadToEnd(); //текст html
                var htmlAsUtf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
                using (MemoryStream htmlContentStream = new MemoryStream(htmlAsUtf8Bytes)) {
                    string partId = "id";
                    AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = mainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                            AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, partId);
                    formatImportPart.FeedData(htmlContentStream);

                    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                    altChunk.Id = partId;

                    mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Где Sample.html (взял [отсюда](http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm)):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <HR>
    <a href="http://somegreatsite.com">Link Name</a>
    is a link to another nifty site
    <H1>This is a Header</H1>
    <H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>
    Send me mail at <a href="mailto:support@yourcompany.com">
        support@yourcompany.com
    </a>.
    <P> This is a new paragraph!
    <P>
        <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>
        <BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B>
        <HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

На выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вашего примера:

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <style>
        .table {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .table td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>  
</head>
<BODY>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Some text</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

На выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD**
Заменит все параграфы, которые состоят только из текста [Html] на наш HTML

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@".docx file", isEditable: true))
            //я вынес файл html как ресурс сборки отдельно, это не принципиально
            using (var htmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Test.Sample.html")) {
                var mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var documentBody = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                var html = new StreamReader(htmlStream).ReadToEnd();
                var htmlAsUtf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

                Random random = new Random();

                var paragraphsToReplace = documentBody.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where(x => x.InnerText.Equals("[Html]")).ToList();

                foreach (var paragraph in paragraphsToReplace) {

                    string partId = $"id_{random.Next()}";

                    AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = mainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                            AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, partId);
                    using (MemoryStream htmlContentStream = new MemoryStream(htmlAsUtf8Bytes)) {
                        formatImportPart.FeedData(htmlContentStream);
                    }
                    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                    altChunk.Id = partId;

                    paragraph.InsertBeforeSelf(altChunk);
                    paragraph.Remove();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы метка [template] совпала с altChunk markup id.

Comment: @endovitskiiy прямо сейчас детально не смогу написать, но AltChunk того же уровня элемент, что и Paragraph, т.е. вам надо будет найти Paragraph с меткой, вызвать у него InserBeforeSelf(),  передать в него объект AltChunk из примера (вместо mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append()) и после удалить объект Paragraph с меткой через его метод Remove(). Получится что вы заменили метку. Надеюсь по памяти правильно расписал.

Comment: Ну смысл понятен, пробую сделать.

Comment: Я так понял что удалиться весь параграф с меткой, а не сама метка

Comment: Да, это элементы одного уровня, их вкладывать нельзя

Comment: Можно пример кода? У меня в итоге не получилось.

Comment: @endovitskiiy добавил

Comment: Понял, спасибо. У меня как раз ошибка была в не уникальности id. Точный текст не помню, но связано с этим.

Comment: Почему-то в docx файл некоторые теги вставляются как текст. Например так: `<p>test</p>`. А таблица преобразуется правильно,  `<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>` - отображается как ячейка таблицы.

Comment: У меня там с кодировкой какая-то проблема, вместо русских букв подставляются иероглифы, либо пустые квадраты, смотря какую кодировку установить в `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);`

Comment: может быть текстовый редактор, который я использую **(tinymce)**, задаёт какую-нибудь другую кодировку?

Comment: У меня почему-то при конвертации документа в pdf замененный html не отображается в pdf-е. Хотя все остальное отображается нормально (текст, картинки). Не понимаю.